# the following command was not found netsh

Tags: c#, netsh

I'm trying execute a couple of "netsh" commands but no matter what I do I keep getting the same error "the following command was not found netsh".

I can verify that the path "C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe" is valid and when I run the same command with the same set of arguments through the command prompt; everything works fine.

This a sample of the code I'm using.

```
ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(System.Environment.SystemDirectory),
                FileName = @"netsh.exe",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                Arguments = String.Format(@"{0}\{1} {2}", System.Environment.SystemDirectory, @"netsh.exe", "wlan start hostednetwork"),
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            };

            Process proc = Process.Start(procInfo);
            proc.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently passing the full pathname in the *arguments*, when I suspect you want to pass it as the *filename*. For example:

```
FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "netsh.exe"),
Arguments = "wlan start hostednetwork"
```

For example, this short but complete program doesn't throw any exceptions - I don't know whether it does what you want, but it doesn't fail with the exception you described:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

class Test
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WorkingDirectory = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory),
            FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "netsh.exe"),
            Arguments = "wlan start hostednetwork",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        };

        Process proc = Process.Start(procInfo);
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

(Note how the code becomes less cluttered when you take advantage of `using` directives instead of using fully-qualified names, by the way.)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work here (Win7). It still says "The following command was not found", however when it says "command", it refers to the arguments after the filename netsh.exe.. For some strange reason..

Comment: @markj: That sounds like it's a problem with the command you're giving to netsh. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I tried the following command: netsh mbn connect interface="Mobile broadband" connmode=name name="TDC Mobil"
The purpose was to connect a mobile broadband connection. I already know that the quotes were the culprits here - in some strange kind of way. I finally got it working by creating a batch file, letting an AutoHotkey script run the batch file, and then making my main application run this script (compiled into an exe file). A true workaround, but a stable and functioning one :)

Comment: And yes, I tried escaping the quotes in 3-4 different ways. Running the batch file directly from my main application as a process returned the same error as well.

Comment: Or actually, I am not a hundred percent sure that the quotes were the problem. I might be missing something else - something obvious somewhere..